# Why isn't Brightcove Player Loading in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, url, uiwebview

I'm a noob to iPhone development and I am having trouble loading the brightcove player into the `UIWebView`. I am well aware that iOS can't play flash, but I don't need to play the video. I just want the player and it's thumbnail to be visible in the webView. When I load the brightcove player via an url link in the webview it works fine, but when I just try to embed the player it doesn't load. Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

MY Code:

```
//Via Url Link
NSString * storyLink = @"http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2228912951001"
NSURL *kitcoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storyLink];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:kitcoURL];
[videoScreen setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[videoScreen loadRequest:requestURL];

//Embedding Player
//Brightcove Player
NSString *htmlStr2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><object id=\"flashObj\" width=\"320\" height=\"230\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" codebase=\"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1\" /><param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#FFFFFF\" /><param name=\"flashVars\" value=\"videoId=2228912951001&playerID=659636031001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBM6WfpHEsDft5laXH9ASJhF&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true\" /><param name=\"base\" value=\"http://admin.brightcove.com\" /><param name=\"seamlesstabbing\" value=\"false\" /><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"swLiveConnect\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\" /><embed src=\"http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" flashVars=\"videoId=2228912951001&playerID=659636031001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBM6WfpHEsDft5laXH9ASJhF&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true\" base=\"http://admin.brightcove.com\" name=\"flashObj\" width=\"320\" height=\"230\" seamlesstabbing=\"false\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowFullScreen=\"true\" swLiveConnect=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash\"></embed></object></body></html>",];

//Load Brightcove Player
[videoScreen loadHTMLString:htmlStr2 baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't loading different HTML via the URL link?

Comment: As far as I cat tell it's all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brightcove Player relies on Adobe Flash, which does not run on iOS.

Comment: So how is it loading when I use the URL link then?

Comment: The URL link is detecting that the device is an iOS device and displaying an HTML5 video instead of the Flash player.  In the `UIWebView` you're hardcoding the Flash player, which is why it's failing.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Apple is so restrictive.  Thanks for the clarification.